# Help with wiring a temperature controller and a solid state relay

Tags: temperature, solid-state-relay

I have a problem that's probably patently obvious to someone in the know but alas, that's not me.

Long and short- I have a 240v heating table (aluminum table with silicone heating pads underneath) that is about 40 years old and it just died.  Unfortunately all of the old parts no longer exist and the original design was part specific.  So after a lot of reverse engineering and brain storming I (with some help) found a solution. 
 The table will be controlled by a Watlow pm3c1cj-aaaabaa, with a simple relay switch to turn the controller on, and a solid state relay to power the heating elements.

I have successfully wired everything according to the diagram my helper gave me but the solid state relay hung me up. Here's the wiring diagram (incomplete) :

Relay is the relay switch to power on the Watlow

Watlow is the pm3c1cj-aaaabaa

The Watlow has the following contacts available: T1, X1, W1, Y1, Cf, Cd, CE

"THC" is the thermocouple

SSR is a Continental rvda/6v40

The SSR has the following contacts: 1/L1, 2/T1, 3/A1, 4/A2

I'm at a loss as to finish up the wiring.  Any help would be massively appreciated.
 [image]

Answer (score 1):

You should read and understand the manual before wiring and setting up the controller or you are likely going to have a bad time.

There are a LOT of internal parameters and settings on these things.

Anyway, here's a clip from what I think is the correct [manual](https://www.watlow.com/products/controllers/temperature-and-process-controllers/ez-zone-pm-controller).

[image]

Presumably this functionality is built into  your particular model.

---

Similarly, SSRs have some nuances that should be understood. The [datasheet](https://www.gavazzionline.com/pdf/RGC_U.pdf) tells us that A1 is + and A2 is -.

Answer (score 0):

The SSRs need a firing card, or at least they're intended to be used with a firing card.
[image: here is a snip from a watlow SSR brochure]

[image: also here is a wiring diagram from a watlow white paper]